# Specify separate .editorconfig files between debug and release configurations

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, editorconfig

I am using VS 2019 16.8.3 and I want to specify some code analysis rules (dotnet_diagnostic.CAXXXX.severity) in the solution .editorconfig file, only for release builds.

When I add rules in a .editorconfig file debug build time increases by a few minutes. All Analyzers checkboxes are not selected to "Run on build" in project properties.

So I want to exclude debug build from code analysis. Is it possible to specify a .editorconfig file only for release builds?

Or is it possible to disable this .editconfig for builds and only apply for manual code analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.editorconfig` file is not a good choice to add the custom analysis rules due to your configuration conditions.

The best way is to use MSBuild function [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019) file  to add them which is more pure.

**1)** Create a ruleset file and add any code analysis which you want to use for **Debug**

**2)** add a file called `Directory.Build.props` under your project folder

[image]

**3)** add these under the file:

```
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">

    <!--the full path of your ruleset file for Debug mode-->
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>xxx\RuleSet1.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>


</Project>
```

**So** when you build your project with **Release**, the ruleset will skip due to the msbuild condition and only works for **Debug** mode.

You can also add another ruleset for Release mode. And add the code Analysis under the corresponding configuration in the respective ruleset files.

Comment: I was watching a pluralsight tutorial and it says rulesets are not going to be maintained well in future and eventually they will be replaced by .editorcofigs. 
Do you have any comment on that?
Reference : https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/visual-studio-2019-code-analysis/table-of-contents

Comment: @CharithJ, there is no `Microsoft` document that indicates VS will abandon ruleset. And for the classic and traditional way of ruleset, Vs has no reason to abandon it, at least it will keep it. And for many users who use ruleset, abandoning it is unscientific. If Microsoft really wants to abandon it, Microsoft will definitely have a buffering method, at least to ensure that the ruleset is still used. I think you do not have to worry too much about this. You can still use ruleset and it is very useful for code analysis.

Comment: Thanks for that! Can you think of any workaround at all to exclude .editorconfig only for debug builds? Or for all builds and execute only manually?
We have nearly thousand rules that may need to add to ruleset if we were to use to use rulesets.

Comment: Maybe try this: `<Choose><When Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'"><ItemGroup><None Include=".editorconfig" /> </ItemGroup> </When>  </Choose>`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. If .editorconfig is in the directory, it takes it into account even without including it the project or solution.

Comment: .editorconfig files will likely integrate better with VS on an on-going basis. Most of the Roslyn tooling for controlling diagnostics levels and the like default to modifying .editorconfig files, even going so far as to create one if necessary.

Comment: [@dogukanarkan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66036795/24874) is the best approach for the future, IMO.

Answer (score 8):

### TLDR

You can set your `.editorconfig` files in `Directory.Build.props` like this:

```
<Project>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">  
        <EditorConfigFiles Include="xxx\debug.editorconfig" Link=".editorconfig"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
        <EditorConfigFiles Include="xxx\release.editorconfig" Link=".editorconfig"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

---

### Deep Dive

We had a same issue in our company. We wanted to set different severity to one specific rule on debug and release configuration. The reason we wanted this was because while the developer was getting a warning in the development environment(in his/her computer), the pull request was given an error at project or solution build phase in the Azure DevOps environment.

By the way, we have a repository named as **CodingGuideline** to store our `.editorconfig` files and to reference some analyzers like **StyleCop**. At the same time, this repository is a nuget package. And this package is referenced in all our repositories.

And we have some solutions as follows:

#### Solution 1

- We can store `.editorconfig` and `review.editorconfig` seperate files. Developers already have repository directory to keep company repositories and everyone put `.editorconfig` to inside this directory manually. (If you don't want to put config file manually, you can try solution 2) In this way, whole repositories will follow same code style and coding rules.
- If any developer create a pull request, **CodingGuideline** repository is being clone to the build directory automatically. After cloning, `review.editorconfig` file is copying named as `.editorconfig`. That's it. When dotnet build command is run and some rules that defined `review.editorconfig` is broken, pull request will throw error.

#### Solution 2

- If we don't want to put config file manually, we can deploy the config file through nuget package. In this option, we store `development.editorconfig` and `review.editorconfig` seperate files. We can't use file name as `.editorconfig` because we cannot deploy file that have this name.
- We should create `CodingGuideline.targets`(*ProjectName.targets*) file to **CodingGuideline** nuget package repository and put this code inside to copy `development.editorconfig` as `.editorconfig`.

  ```
  <Project>
      <Target Name="CodingGuidelineEditorConfig" AfterTargets="BeforeBuild" BeforeTargets="CoreBuild">
          <Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\development.editorconfig" DestinationFiles=".editorconfig" />
      </Target>
  </Project>
  ```
- When we add **CodingGuideline** reference to any repository with , `CodingGuideline.targets` will trigger automatically and copy `.editorconfig` file to the every project root directory.
- Pull request section is same as solution 1.

---

### Summary

As you can see, we don't actually need to `Directory.Build.props` definition on both solutions. But of course, if you want to keep both config files in project, I cannot interfere with your business.

By the way, we decided to use **.editorconfig** instead of **ruleset**. Because this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#convert-an-existing-ruleset-file-to-editorconfig-file) says that **ruleset** is deprecated as you said and they recommend to use **.editorconfig**.

I think first solution is better than second solution. Because `.editorconfig` file is unique in directory level, none of the repositories/solutions/projects contain `.editorconfig` file. But developer have to put `.editorconfig` file to root repository directory by hand.

Just the opposite, second solution is more automated but whole repositories have to contain `.editorconfig`. Maybe there is a way to hide it from solution explorer but I couldn't research completely.

[image: Every project has a .editorconfig file]

Answer (score 0):

You could also try keeping your `.editorconfig` file and adding this to your project (or a `Directory.Build.props` file somewhere):

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <RunCodeAnalysis Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">false</RunCodeAnalysis>
</PropertyGroup>
```