# How to change tab and indentation size *easily* in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have to work on different projects, some of which (by management decision) should be formatted with two spaces per indentation, while in other projects we use four spaces. This means that I need to change the editor settings multiple times per day. Going to Tools->Options and navigating to the necessary page is very annoying and distracting.

I thought about some macros or other automation, but none seem to be available in Visual Studio 2022 for Windows. There exist some third-party extensions for macro automation, but they seem to be for the editor window only.

I even considered writing some extension for VS and assigning it to toolbar buttons, but the open question is whether an extension can change those settings in code, i.e. whether there exists a corresponding API method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably want an [EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022) file per solution or project.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, thank you. Just tested it, and it's an ok solution. Not perfect because it requires manual placing of a file to every project's directory, and due to specifics of my work, there are plenty of projects around. But that's better than nothing, that's for sure.

Comment: You don't need a file per project, only one at a top-level project. The file applies to all its subfolders. You can separate the projects you want by settings and put an `.editorconfig` at the root

Comment: Besides, how would a *macro* decide what settings to use? You'd have to either run it by hand (while editorconfig is automatic) or it would need to check *something* to see which settings to apply.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos projects are scattered, they are not subprojects. As for "manually" - yes, two buttons on the toolbar (for 2 spaces and 4 spaces) would do miracles. Where automation is available (Office), that's how things work. It's a pity that Microsoft doesn't provide easy automation in VS.

Comment: `editorconfig` is fully automatic. You're asking for a manual way instead.  In any case it's [possible to specify editorconfig files conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65769873/specify-separate-editorconfig-files-between-debug-and-release-configurations) with a `Directory.Build.props`. If you want to apply settings manually, you *can* [create  macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio). That macro may change settings, or it may copy a specific `editorconfig` inside the project so you don't have to run it again

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That macro plugin is for VS up to 2019 . And yes, sometimes, manual is better than fully automatic :).

Comment: Yes, I see it was abandoned, even though VS had macros for the last 20+ years. The other option is to create a VS addin yourself. Frankly, most developers no longer want macros, they use scripts for automation, which are far more flexible and can run in CI/CD pipelines. Macros can't. What you ask is really not that different from creating a new editorconfig file from a custom template which is already possible. You can [create file templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates) from a folder's contents

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, to create a script, it's necessary to know whether VS supports changing the needed attribute in code (and if it does - which methods are there); and that was in my question :)